# Tool to test iOS asset sizes?

Tags: ios

I look for a tool / script to test if all iOS assets have the right size.

For example:
I have foo.png with 50x50, foo@2x.png with 100x100 and foo@3x.png with 125x125

Is there a tool which shows me that foo@3x.png has the wrong size?

Comment: Don't know whether there is an app for that, but there is an app called "prepo" which if you insert max resolution image, then it will return the desired images in 1x, 2x, 3x, also can give app icon images for all sizes.